# How dataframe sort values from a to b not to aa not alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I've got a tricky problem. I have a dataframe, and one column is 'Group'

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| SA | x |
| X | x |
| SAA | x |
| SB | x |

If I use df sort function, it will give me:

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| SA | x |
| SAA | x |
| SB | x |
| X | x |

However I want to get:

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| SA | x |
| SB | x |
| SAA | x |
| X | x |

Comment: python pandas dataframe

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
def key_fn(s):
    return [(v[0], len(v), v) for v in s]

df = df.sort_values(by="Group", key=key_fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Group Value
0    SA     x
3    SB     x
2   SAA     x
1     X     x
```

Comment: Nice one Andrej ;)